# Why is the variable PS1 a problem for direnv when sourcing venv

Tags: python-venv, direnv

I use direnv v2.21.2 and want that the hook activates my previous created `.venv`. If I use just `source .venv/bin/activate` my environment gets activated, but PS1 reacts with an error message. I actually have no clue what to do with the `PS1` variable but it seems not a big issue since I use `starship`as my prompt. Not completly shure.

Using instead `layout python3` works fine without error but creates the extra venv which I don't need. Any Ideas?

EDIT: The Error Message which is produced by direnv if `unset PS1` is not used:

```
direnv: PS1 cannot be exported. For more information see https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/PS1
```

The Message leads actually to the correct information, but doesn't help much about why the problem exist.

Comment: Ok I found the information in the wiki to unset PS1. But do not really understand for what PS1 is needed, maybe this can be awnsered.

Comment: What error do you get? `activate` does little more than try to prepend the name of the virtual environment to your current value of `PS1`. It may be doing so in a way that `starship` (whatever that is) doesn't react well with.

Comment: starship is a promt (kind of compareable to powerlevel10k but works in most shells) I edit the Post and append the error message I got without unset PS1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `export`ing `PS1` triggered a bug in Bash 3.0, and direnv did not have a way to `set` certain variable instead of `export`ing them. I don't know what bug in Bash was triggered exactly.

- *Interesting. I have another variable [like CDPATH –ed] that would best be set instead of exported: PS1. Direnv doesn't really have a mechanism for that. If I get around to rewrite direnv I will take that into account.*
  — [zimbatm commented on issue 251 on Mar 11, 2017](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/251)
- *PS1 is on the direnv blacklist because of a bug in bash 3.x* — [zimbatm commented on issue 331 on Feb 20, 2018](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/331#issuecomment-367015404)
- *// PS1 should not be exported, fixes problem in bash* — [comment in env_diff.go](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/cb5222442cb9804b1574954999f6073cc636eff0/internal/cmd/env_diff.go#L19)